# How to show multiple random childs from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show random users from Firebase Realtime Database .I am currently able to show one random user from my Firebase Realtime database but what i want to do is show 6 random users on to my recyclerview at once .But i am unable to figure out how to add query for same without getting an error at runtime.

[image: DataBase Structure]

Mycode

```
    public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    String TAG = "MyTag";
    ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;

    List<String> UserIdsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public UsersFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();


        //readUser();
        RandomUsers();



        return view;
    }


    private void RandomUsers() {

        //mUsers.add((User) UserIdsList);



        mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
        mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference UserIdsRef = rootRef.child("UserIds");

        ValueEventListener mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String userIDS = ds.getKey();
                    UserIdsList.add(userIDS);
                }

                int UserListSize = UserIdsList.size();
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(UserListSize));

                Random random=new Random();
                int random1=random.nextInt(UserListSize);

               // int Rdm= UserIdsList.get(new Random().nextInt(UserListSize));

                DatabaseReference UserRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(UserIdsList.get(random1));
                Log.d(TAG,"UserRef  "+ String.valueOf(UserRef));

                //new Random().nextInt(UserListSize)

                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        mUsers.add(user);
                        mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("First").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Name called  "+name);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + databaseError.toException()); //Don't ignore errors!
                    }
                };

                UserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

                //UserRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);

                Query query2 = UserRef.limitToFirst(2);
                query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        UserIdsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(mValueEventListener);

        //UserIdsRef.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);

    }

}
```

> UserAdapter.java

```
    public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    private List<String> UserIdsList;

    private boolean ischat;

    String theLastMessage;

    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> mUsers,boolean ischat) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mUsers = mUsers;
        this.ischat=ischat;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);

        return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final User user=mUsers.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(user.getFirst());

        if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        if (ischat){
            lastMessage(user.getId(), holder.last_msg);
        } else {
            holder.last_msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (ischat){
            if (user.getStatus().equals("online")){
                holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("UserName",user.getFirst());
                intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());
                intent.putExtra("ImageURL",user.getImageURL());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView username;
        public ImageView profile_image;
        private ImageView img_on;
        private ImageView img_off;
        private  TextView last_msg;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username=itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            profile_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            img_on = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_on);
            img_off = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_off);
            last_msg=itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_msg);
        }
    }

    private void lastMessage(final String userid, final TextView last_msg){
        theLastMessage = "default";
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null) {
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                                chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                            theLastMessage = chat.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }

                switch (theLastMessage){
                    case  "default":
                        last_msg.setText("No Message");
                        break;

                    default:
                        last_msg.setText(theLastMessage);
                        break;
                }

                theLastMessage = "default";
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Data Snapshot

```
DataSnapshot { key = KRhmaWXCctMHbU1Z6NAWRGGw2ag2, value = {EmailId=abc@gmail.com, First=shivam} }
```

Comment: UserRef.startAt(UserIdsList.get(random1)).limitToFirst(2) => doesn't work?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir i get the following error than    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.shivam.chatapp2.Model.User.getFirst()' on a null object reference
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Adapters.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:59)
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Adapters.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:30)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir i can upload code for adapter if its needed

Comment: It says User.getFirst()  is  null. Why?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir UserRef is pointing towards a Uid i think that can be a reason

Comment: Can you change query. And share dataSnapshot.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I added the code for UserAdapter

Comment: Sorry, I said it wrong. No need adapter. Just change query as .limitToFirst(2) and run debug mode. Add breakpoint to line "User user = ". You can see the dataSnapshot now. Copy value and share.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir It also show mUsers Size=0

Comment: So dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class) doesn't work. You should fix it. I don't understand why doesn't work.

Comment: I did come up with something please suggest if its good option or not .I added another listener below event listener to get another random user and it does work by the way and returns two random users

Comment: Does it work?...

Comment: Yess it works..

Comment: So you can remove UserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir No, actually i have to use two listeners for two random users for example eventListener gives me one random user and another listener eventListener2 gives me second random user.First i add eventListener and than eventListener2 inside mValueEventListener

Comment: It is not good option. It should be one listener

Comment: rootRef.child("Users").startAt(UserIdsList.get(random1)).limitToFirst(6);

Comment: Only use this query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211347/discussion-between-ravi-malik-and-kasim-ozdemir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DatabaseReference UserRef = rootRef.child("Users").orderByKey().startAt(UserIdsList.get(random1)).lim‌​itToFirst(6);
  ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
         mUsers.add(user);
         mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         String name = dataSnapshot.child("First").getValue(String.class);
         Log.d(TAG, "Name called  "+name);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + databaseError.toException()); 
      }
};

UserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```